# Unable to insert data to ROOM database in Jetpack Compose

Tags: database, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I have problem with adding data to ROOM database.
I already create:
DATA CLASS,
DAO,
APP DATABASE

https://github.com/DawidSiudeja/Tournament/tree/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/tournamentapp/database

I have no idea how to save it into database.

I was trying to make sth like this:

```
val db = getDatabase(context)
db.TournamentDao.insert(Tournament())
```

but i have to pass context to the function and i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a repository with your method for inserting, like this:

```
class TournamentsRepository(database: Appdatabase){

  val tournaments = //wherever the source of your data is
  suspend fun insertTournaments(){
    database.tournamentsDao.insert(tournaments)
  }
}
```

Also, in your database, change:

```
abstract fun TournamentsDao(): TournamentsDao
```

to

```
abstract val tournamentsDao: TournamentsDao
```